# Can we write a generic method that takes element as parameter and returns the result. (e.g.method returning the result of isDisplayed() function)?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am writing selenium code (Java) for a form page that consists of 5 different elements (Textfield, radio, checkbox, list, dropdown). I have to check the visibility of each elements (e.g, txtfield.isDisplayed()).

I am following page object model and I have a page class that defines all elements and methods to work with the elements. At present, I have written 5 different methods for each element to return visibility status. That works fine.

However, I want to understand if it is possible to have one method that possibly can take the element as parameter and return the result.

For example:

```
String idForTextField = "id-text-field"


public boolean isElementVisible(String input){
        return input.isDisplayed()
}
```

Problem I am facing is that to call the function isDisplayed(), we need actual element name ("idForTextField"); parameter name ("input") will not work even if "idForTextField" was passed as a parameter.

Is there any implementation that will help to achieve this?

Please note that form elements are identified differently. Two of them by id and three of them xpath.

Thanks.

Comment: I should have mentioned that the form elements are identified differently in the form.  Two of them by id and three of them by xpath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can well pass an xPath for your elements to a generic method.

```
public static boolean isDisplayed(String){
    return driver.findElement(By.xpath('YOUR XPATH HERE')).isDisplayed();
}
```

To help you with xPath, you can get it from inspecting the element in google chrome.

Note: Also, this method throws Exception if the element is not found. Handle this accordingly as well as per your requirement. Good luck!

Edit 1: You can also do this,

```
enum FindBy{
   ID,XPATH
}

public static void isVisible(String,FindBy findBy){
    Webelement element = null;
    switch(findBy){
         case XPATH:
         element = driver.findElement(By.xpath('YOUR XPATH HERE'));
         break;
         case ID:
         element= driver.findElement(By.id('YOUR ID HERE'));
         break;
    }
    return element!=null && element.isVisible();
}
```

Also, another way is to define an enum with methods

```
enum FindBy {
       ID
       @Override
       public WebElement getElement(String){
          return driver.findElement(By.id('String'));
        },
       XPATH
     @Override
       public WebElement getElement(String){
          return driver.findElement(By.xpath('String'));
        },   
public abstract WebElement getElement(String);

public boolean isVisible(String) {
    return getElement(String).isVisible();
 }
}
```

You can call it as `FindBy.ID.isVisible(String);`

Comment: Thanks @mahamed-anees-a. I should have mentioned in my query that my form elements are identified differently for different elements like two of them by id and three of them by xpath. Hence, choosing the right locator is difficult. e.g., By.id vs. By.xpath. Or do you suggest I force all element to be found using xpath?

Comment: I am not forcing to find all by xPath, but if you do, it is more easy to manage them with a generic method and not bloating your codebase unnecessarily.

Comment: I agree with you on having uniform approach on finding elements. I am just wondering if there is any other way to achieve this that I am not aware of. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks @mohamed-anees-a. Could you please help explain the second edit code. I will accept it as workaround for now. Appreciate your time and effort.

Comment: You can refer this -> http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java/enums.html#enum-abstract-methods

Answer (score 1):

I think you can pass WebElement directly in method argument so that isDisplayed() wil be applicable to every element whether it found by id or xpath.

Code snippets for creating method to check if element displayed or not suppose following submit button is your webelement

```
WebElement submitButton=driver.findElementBy.xpath("your xpath or use by.id");


    //method to check visibility of web element
     public boolean isElementVisible(Webelement element)
    { return element.isDisplayed();
     }
```

Comment: Thanks @shweta. Could you please share the code snippet if it has worked for you.

Comment: @shweta Can you club up this answer of your's with your other answer for this same question?